# Google Glass Wildcard Voice Command

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, voice-recognition

I have voice commands in my Google Glass app working, with a `R.id.add_item` and `R.id.remove_item` for a list-type app. However, I would like to be able to let the user say, "Add Item, Apple". I cannot find any information on how to do this.

My `main.xml` file looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/add_item"
    android:title="Add Item" />
<item android:id="@+id/remove_item"
    android:title="Remove Item" />
</menu>
```

And my `onMenuItemSelected` is

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    if (featureId == WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS || featureId ==  Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add_item:
                break;
            case R.id.remove_item:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

I don't know where I would add this code, or how I would do so. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You add onMenuItem to your activity....

I think reading the code again you could see where it fits in the bigger scope.
https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice

You can try here to see a sample app with voice recognition:
https://github.com/RIVeR-Lab/google_glass_driver/tree/master/android/RobotManager/src/com/riverlab/robotmanager

Comment: Would I be looking at the line, `ArrayList<String> voiceResults = getIntent().getExtras()
        .getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);`?